# Using 8192 bit keys GPG

Tags: pgp, gnupg, key-generation

I am interested in generating 8192 bit keys out of curiosity.  I know that 4096 bit keys is the maximum key strength that is recommended, but I would like to know how to increase the size.  I have tried to modify one of the file's in C and then compile it, but I failed and it did not work. The terminal would try to attempt to generate entropy, but it failed out after about a minute or so. Can someone please guide me how to make GPG key size larger than 4096?

I would appreciate any help.  Once again, I understand this is not recommended, but I would really like to know how to do this.  Cheers.

Comment: "one of the files" - what files?

Comment: Hi @schroeder, thanks for the reply.  This is the file I modified: g10/keygen.c.  I was following a guide on a blog post and tried to modify the line there, but it didn't work for me.  Thanks again.

Comment: Then it looks like a problem for the developer of that software. I'm not sure how we could help.

Comment: Can you possibly link me to a guide that I could follow?  I must be doing something wrong.  I saw another post on this forum where the user followed the same instructions and was successful I believe.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jordan do you understand why it's not recommended ?